# Esperar a la resolución de multiples solicitudes ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Supongamos que hay dos solicitudes concurrentes de Ajax en progreso.

¿Qué método podría usar para rastrear estas solicitudes y desactivar las funciones de manejo solo cuando ambas solicitudes se hayan completado con éxito?

Comment: Quiero lanzar ciertas preguntas que me he encontrado por la red. No tengo código porque no la he desarrollado yo (Me parece ridículo meter un código fallido para hacerla pasar por una pregunta "válida"). Si se han de borrar o replantear, adelante, sin ningún problema. Simplemente creo que son interesantes para cualquier usuario que se encuentre ante estas dudas

Comment: Si pudieras mostrar un ejemplo de lo que has intentado o por lo menos una idea seria de mucha ayuda para dar una respuesta satisfactoria.

Comment: @Einer en ello estoy. No son problemas que me hayan surgido ami, si no que son dudas que he encontrado con bastante frecuencia en inglés y no he encontrado una respuesta satisfactoria traducida al castellano.

Comment: La parte de *desactivar las funciones de manejo* no la entiendo... ¿A qué se refiere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternativa a la respuesta anterior, si usas promesas nativas, creo sería más prático usar [`Promise#all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise/all) para este propósito.

```js
const getCountries = () => fetch('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all');
const getBeers = () => fetch('https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers');

Promise.all([getCountries(), getBeers()]).then(onSuccess).catch(console.error);

function onSuccess(promises) {
  promises[0]
    .json()
    .then(countries => countries.map(c => c.name))
    .then((data) => {
      console.log('Countries: ', data);
    });
  promises[1]
    .json()
    .then(beers => beers.map(b => b.name))
    .then((data) => {
      console.log('Beers: ', data);
    });
}
```

La función `onSuccess` se ejecutará **solo si ambas promesas han sido resueltas de forma satisfactoria**, ya que si una falla, toda la operación fallará.

Comment: ¿Y que diferencia podemos encontrar entre promise.all - then y $.when - then por ejemplo? No termino de encajar del todo las promesas.

Comment: El concepto de promesas es compartido entre jQuery y otros como Bluebird y el nativo Promise (incluído como parte de la especificación de la ECMAScript). Dicho esto, aunque de manera conceptual son similares, en la implementación tienen diferencias importantes. Hay un término que es importante y es la **estandarización**. Ten en cuenta que si tienes ya de manera nativa en el lenguaje herramientas para peticiones y promesas, deberías ir dejando de lado librerías que hacen lo mismo.

Answer (score 1):

### [$.when()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)

Acepta cualquier número de objetos Diferidos como argumentos y ejecuta una función cuando todos se resuelven.

Eso significa que, si desea iniciar (por ejemplo) cuatro solicitudes ajax, luego realice una acción cuando hayan terminado, podría hacer algo como esto:

```
$.when(ajax1(), ajax2(), ajax3(), ajax4()).done(function(a1, a2, a3, a4){
...
});

function ajax1() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: "algunaURL",
        dataType: "json",
        data:  tusJsonDatos,
        ...
    });
}
```

Respuesta traducida de la siguiente [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709597/wait-until-all-jquery-ajax-requests-are-done) en inglés

Opinión del autor original:

*En mi opinión, crea una sintaxis limpia y clara, y evita la participación de variables globales como ajaxStart y ajaxStop, que podrían tener efectos secundarios no deseados a medida que su página se desarrolle.*

*Si necesitas un control más profundo sobre los modos de falla de los scripts ajax, etc., puede guardar el objeto devuelto por `.when()` - es un objeto jQuery `Promise` que abarca todas las consultas ajax originales. Puede invocar `.then()` o `.fail()` para agregar manejadores detallados de éxito / falla.*